# Outputting audio to paired bluetooth device?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I ride an off-road motorcycle on the unsurfaced road network of ancient byways in the UK.  It's great fun, but I've yet to find a good turn-by-turn application suitable for this purpose.  So, I figured I'd write one :)

I have a bluetooth system in my helmet.  Is there any way of streaming audio to a paired bluetooth device from an iphone app.  I can't see any reference to this in the SDK docs.  I don't use the TomTom app, but I guess that must do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. It's very well documented in the Apple Docs.

[IOBluetoothDevice](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothDevice_h/Classes/IOBluetoothDevice/)

Here's a topic that could be of help too:

[Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386598/create-and-send-a-bluetooth-command-frame-in-cocoa)

I think it you pair the Bluetooth device, then using it to receive audio shouldn't be hard.

Having said that I modified my answer, because Headphones ( when paired via bluetooth ), should appear as routes in Core Audio ( making it trivial to pass audio to them ). If you want to use anything sophisticated with bluetooth ( more than just passing audio , I think [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is your best shot. )

Hope I helped

Comment: Note that those are Mac-specific references.  IOBluetooth is not part of the public API for the iPhone.

Comment: Modified answer now, hope it helps.